# Voltage-voltage Feedback and common-collector analysis?

Tags: amplifier, bjt, negative-feedback, common-collector

*(This question is related to this one [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/536335/negative-feedback-from-block-diagram-to-circuit-components?noredirect=1#comment1387502_536335), where I attempted to understand how the discrete component values in a negative feedback amplifier are represented by the closed-loop gain and feedback factor.)*

Today, I'm hoping to understand voltage-controlled voltage feedback a little better.  My plan is to begin with a schematic of a common-collector amplifier and use it to define loop gain and feedback factor.  **Is this analysis correct?**

I'll begin with a block diagram showing the internal amplifier and feedback network:

[image]

As I understand it, the signal \$v_s\$ will be significantly reduced by the feedback network \$K\$ enough that there will be a minuscule voltage presented to the amplifier \$A_v\$.  The voltage output will be nearly the same as the signal, but with a lower output impedance and higher current.  Below is the circuit I'm working with:

[image]

**1. Determining \$v_{in}\$**

If I start with a KVL loop on the input side, I get...

\$v_s=v_{in}+v_f\$

Replacing \$v_{f}\$ with an expression including \$R_E\$...

\$v_s=v_{in}+i_ER_E\$, and then replacing \$i_E\$ with a known component value...

\$v_s=v_{in}+(\frac{\beta+1}{\beta})i_bR_E\$, and then replacing \$i_b\$ with \$g_mv_{in}\$...

\$v_s=v_{in}+(\frac{\beta+1}{\beta})g_mv_{in}R_E\$

\$v_s=\frac{v_s}{[1+(\frac{\beta+1}{\beta})g_mR_E]}\$

**2. Determining \$v_{out}\$**

\$v_{out}\$ is a simpler matter; it is simply dependent on \$R_E\$.

\$v_{out}=i_eR_E\$

\$v_{out}=(\frac{\beta+1}{\beta})i_bR_E\$

\$v_{out}=(\frac{\beta+1}{\beta})g_mv_{in}R_E\$

**3. Determining open-loop gain**

Open-loop gain is simply the action of the internal amplifier, expressed in terms of \$v_{in}\$ and \$v_{out}\$.

\$A_v = \frac{v_{out}}{v_{in}}\$

\$A_v = \frac{(\frac{\beta+1}{\beta})g_mv_{in}R_E}{v_{in}}\$

\$A_v = \frac{(\beta+1)g_mR_E}{\beta}\approx g_mR_E\$

So, the open-loop gain is fairly simple.

**4. Determining closed-loop gain**

Closed-loop gain will use the signal voltage instead of \$v_{in}\$, so...
\$A_f=\frac{v_{out}}{v_s}\$

\$A_f = \frac{(\frac{\beta+1}{\beta})g_mv_{in}R_E}{v_{in}[1+(\frac{\beta+1}{\beta})g_mR_E]}\$

cancelling out \$v_{in}\$...

\$A_f = \frac{(\frac{\beta+1}{\beta})g_mR_E}{[1+(\frac{\beta+1}{\beta})g_mR_E]}\approx 1\$

We can approximate this to 1, as the \$\beta\$ expressions and the 1 in the denominator become negligible.

**5. Checking against the circuit**

Given the circuit values above, we can verify our results.  DC analysis gives a quiescent current of \$3mA\$.  That gives us:

\$g_m=\frac{I_{CQ}}{V_T} = \frac{3mA}{25mV} = 0.12\$

\$A_v = \frac{(\beta+1)g_mR_E}{\beta}\approx g_mR_E\$

\$A_v = \frac{(250+1)0.12*4000}{250}=481.92\$

\$A_f = \frac{(\frac{\beta+1}{\beta})g_mR_E}{[1+(\frac{\beta+1}{\beta})g_mR_E]}\approx 1\$

\$A_f = \frac{(\frac{250+1}{250})0.12*4000}{[1+(\frac{250+1}{250})0.12*4000]}=0.998\$

And what is \$K\$, the feedback factor?  Well, if

\$A_f = \frac{A_v}{1+A_vK}\$, then \$K = \frac{482.92}{481.92}=1.002\$

So, the circuit should change the voltage by a factor of 0.998, a barely-detectable change.  What are the exact voltages \$v_{in}\$ and \$v_f\$?

Assuming a \$v_s=10v\$ input, we would expect:

\$v_{in} = \frac{v_s}{[1+(\frac{\beta+1}{\beta})g_mR_E]}\$
\$v_{in} =\frac{10}{[1+(\frac{250+1}{250})0.12*4000]}=20.7mV\$

And for \$v_{out}\$...

\$v_{out}=(\frac{\beta+1}{\beta})g_mv_{in}R_E\$

\$v_{out}=(\frac{250+1}{250})0.12*0.0207*4000=9.98v\$

**6. To summarize**

The output voltage is nearly the input voltage, missing by only \$20mV\$.  All of this checks out in simulation, so I ask you ... have I analyzed this correctly?  Thanks!

Comment: The Vout and gain are  incorrect. Av is gmRc(common emitter) but not for a common collector  or voltage follower as you have shown . Also for DC Q point  base load = Zb= hFE * Re which affects Vb divider then estimate Vbe=0.65 V to get Vout for  DC

Comment: your 20mV attenuation depends on a ratio just below 1.000 on the undefined assumed input you used  I get Av=0.955 and Vo=12.1, which may be ideal for a 24V supply

Comment: @Tony can you explain more what expression is correct for gain?  I neglected the role of \$r_e\$, is that the problem?

Comment: Also, @Tony, I don't see that I used gmRc anywhere (there isn't a collector resistor).  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy my test input was 10v, how did you get 12.1v output?  Could you please clarify?

Comment: 12.1Vdc ok. is for DC

Comment: yes Emitter Followers must consider \$r_e\$ if you expect more than 2 sig figs also you should specify frequency for Zc assumed =0 in your case.

Comment: Also for large signal analysis r_e changes , so the assumptions are only for small signals.  A better design uses negative feedback as emitter current affects the gain. And load regulation... or at least a constant current sink.