# Negative feedback in collecter-to-base bias BJT circuit

Tags: amplifier, bjt, negative-feedback

I'd like to calculate the 'feedback factor', \$\gamma\$, for the following simple amplifier. By definition of \$\gamma\$, the base voltage is \$V_\text{i}-\gamma V_\text{o}\$, where  \$V_\text{i}\$ is the input signal voltage, and \$V_\text{o}\$ is the a.c. part of the collector (output) voltage. On the figure, \$I_\text{o}\$ and \$I_\text{f}\$ are the a.c. parts of the currents passing through R2 and R1, respectively. The book I'm reading says that \$\gamma\$ is equal to \$I_\text{f}/I_\text{o}\$. It also assumes that \$R_1\$ is 'much larger than the input resistance of the amplifier.'

I think we have \$V_\text{o}=R_\text{2}I_\text{o}\$ and \$V_\text{i}-\gamma V_\text{o}=V_\text{o}-R_1 I_\text{f}\$, but I can't go much further, partly because I don't know what to do with \$V_\text{i}\$ here.

[image]

Comment: You can't specify a function: NFB=f(R1). You need two other parameters, which may be R2 and Vcc but don't have to be those two. Normally, you know your Vcc and have an idea about what you want for R2. Usually, it's best in this case to set the quiescent current as high as possible (you are looking for high gain, after all.) So R1 isn't really a choice. It's a computed value. And it's NFB will be whatever it is as a result of setting up the quiescent DC point. So both R1 and its effective NFB are outputs of a design, neither of them inputs to it. So one is not usually a function of the other.

Comment: That said, you can, if you want, think about the open loop gain (if you can work out the DC operating point) without the NFB and then look at the fact that R1 forms a voltage divider against \$r_{\pi}\$ and that will be your NFB factor -- the portion of the open loop output that is fed back to the input. The process will be to first find the DC quiescent operating point, as this determines \$r_{\pi}\$, \$r_e^{\,'}\$, and the open loop gain. Once you have that, you can work out the local NFB due to R1. Then you can apply that to the standard open-loop to closed-loop voltage gain equation.

Comment: But the main point I want to get across to you is that this topology has very, very few controllable parameters. Setting the local NFB is pretty much ***never*** one of them. Neither is setting \$R_1\$. Sure, technically, one or the other of those could be an input parameter. But they almost never are. Other factors are first and foremost, given how few choices there are. So \$R_1\$ and its NFB are outputs of a design, not inputs. There's no need for \$NFB=f\left(R_1,\left[V_\text{CC},R_2\right]\right)\$ or for \$R_1=g\left(NFB,\left[V_\text{CC},R_2\right]\right)\$. You could. But why?

Comment: @jonk, Thanks for your time. The book (_Success in Electronics_ by Tom Duncan) assumes that  \$R_1\$ is "much larger than the input resistance of the amplifier." No extra information is given. This is the first time I'm calculating "feedback factor" for a circuit, and I don't understand why the book says \$\gamma=I_\text{f}/I_\text{o}\$.

Comment: It's not that high, assuming I'm right assuming that \$I_o\$ for these purposes can be taken close to the collector's quiescent current. If so, then the ratio is about \$\frac1{\beta}\$ (thereabouts) and that would be too much NFB, I think. Suppose the quiescent collector current is \$3\:\text{mA}\$ (\$r_e^{\,'}\approx 9\:\Omega\$), \$R_\text{C}=2.7\:\text{k}\Omega\$, and that \$\beta\approx 200\$ (NFB about 0.005 according to the author.) I'd guess the open loop gain to be about 300, then. If the author's NFB were right then I'd find the closed loop gain to be 120. It'll be more than that.

Comment: Perhaps I just don't understand the variables the author is using here? Perhaps the author is talking about the DC operating point and creating a factor to help in working that out and nothing about the AC voltage gain, at all?

Comment: I guess part of the reason I'm asking all this is because the signal source impedance isn't specified. As such, it is assumed to be zero. Given a zero source impedance, the base will be driven ***hard***. The base resistor can't fight that and so the NFB will always be negligible in this case. So the whole AC NFB thing just doesn't make a lot of sense to me, I guess. Something's amiss.

Comment: @jonk, I hope you are not assuming that \$I_\text{o}\$ is the total current (d.c. + a.c.). As I said, it's only the a.c. part, which may be lower than the quiescent current (d.c.).

Comment: I was thinking that. Sorry. My point about the zero source impedance compared to the base resistance remains, though.

Comment: @jonk, and the same is true about the other \$I\$ and \$V\$ variables. They represent a.c. parts.

Comment: Doesn't matter. With zero source impedance the base resistance simply doesn't have any impact worth mentioning. I don't see how NFB is meaningful without a source impedance greater than zero.

Comment: @jonk, the book is very basic. It doesn't cover Ebers-Moll equation, for example. By avoiding enough mathematics, it has made things confusing sometimes.

Comment: I can't help. The source is assumed to be a voltage source with zero impedance, unless specified. The capacitor is assumed to have negligible AC impedance, as well. So the base is, effectively, being driven by a *voltage source*. How can the base resistor have any impact on that? The source voltage would swallow it up, completely. There's nothing to compute. The NFB is zero given a zero source impedance. You don't need Ebers-Moll for that.

Comment: Try to use a current source as an input signal source instead of a voltage source.  Then you will have NFB. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/538778/transimpedance-topology-from-block-diagram-to-schematic

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/543163/how-do-i-analyze-this-negative-feedback

Answer (score 3):

### Secular Apologetics

In the above comments (my apologies for so many), I've pointed out the fact that the source impedance is important if you want to calculate an NFB figure for the base resistor, \$R_1\$, in your schematic. Without a source impedance, and therefore assuming it is zero, the base resistance cannot have an NFB effect as the input voltage source completely drives the base and there's no possibility for the base resistance to impact it through an NFB process. It simply cannot occur, in theory anyway.

The input capacitance matters, too. But again, in this case, the usual assumption is that the input capacitance reactance is negligible -- meaning zero for analysis purposes. So, again, I have to repeat the fact that you cannot compute an NFB for the base resistor if your input voltage source has zero driving impedance. I cannot make it any plainer than that.

### A Question about the Question

Now, if there is a source impedance to account for, then there can be an NFB factor computed. However, there comes a question. If there is a source impedance, then the BJT circuit will load it down and diminish it before it has a chance to be amplified by the stage. So what exactly do you mean when you ask for the NFB factor that the base resistance contributes? Do you want to calculate the final, closed loop gain using the open loop gain and a single, *effective* NFB factor, directly? Is that the NFB you want -- this NFB of the *first kind*? Or do you want to compute the final, closed loop gain by multiplying the closed loop gain equation using a *different* NFB factor (of the *second kind*) and then multiply that result by the attenuation that results before applying that equation? These are two different NFB figures and therefore two different equations to compute them.

So, even the question itself isn't clear.,

But the problem is interesting enough that I will post a result for the NFB of the *first kind*. In short, you can use it to compute the final voltage gain by directly applying it in this form: \$A_{_\text{CL}}=\frac{A_{_\text{OL}}}{1+A_{_\text{OL}}\cdot B_{_\text{NFB}}}\$. The equation will take all of the factors into account, including the attenuation.

(That said, I did simplify things just a little bit. For example, I completely neglected the base resistance loading when accounting for the attenuation factor. This is reasonable, because the base resistance is so much larger in all cases than the other factors. So it has negligible effect and I left it out, as unimportant.)

### The Nub of the Matter

Here's how you can calculate the NFB that is caused by the base resistor, which takes into account the attenuation of the input, as well. This allows for a very simple calculation in estimating the closed loop voltage gain.

$$B_{_\text{NFB}}=\frac{R_{_\text{SRC}}}{\left[\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R_{_\text{C}}\right]\:\mid\mid\: \left[R_{_\text{C}}+R_{_\text{B}}+\left(R_{_\text{SRC}}\mid\mid r_\pi\right)\right]}$$

In the above, \$r_\pi\$ is computed in the usual fashion. You need to know the quiescent collector current and an estimated \$\beta\$ for the BJT to get it (well, the temperature, too, of course.) I chose to ignore your use of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ and instead assigned \$R_{_\text{C}}\equiv R_2\$ and \$R_{_\text{B}}\equiv R_1\$. Obviously, \$R_{_\text{SRC}}\$ is the input signal voltage source impedance.

The above figure will be too low because of several factors. One of them is the Ohmic emitter resistance. This is often some few tenths of an Ohm and it is often significant enough that it should be accounted for. It's not, above. There are other factors I also ignored. So the above figure will perhaps be about 4% low. But it's tolerably simple to compute, so I went with it.

### Using the NFB Figure

To use the above calculated figure, you will need to work out the open loop voltage gain, \$A_{_\text{OL}}\$. Since you already have \$r_\pi\$ for the above calculation, this is pretty easy. First compute \$r_e^{\,'}=\frac{r_\pi}{\beta+1}\$. Then: \$A_{_\text{OL}}\approx \frac{R_{_\text{C}}}{r_e^{\,'}}\$.

But again, this isn't taking into account the emitter's Ohmic resistance nor the Early Effect. So I'd discount this figure a bit. Since these stages are mostly operated as small signal devices in collector current ranges of a few milliamps or less, I'd add about \$1\:\Omega\$ before using \$r_e^{\,'}\$ for the calculation.

(The other situations are ones you don't encounter. And if you did, the paper and pencil approach is out the window, anyway, as other issues then dominate and the only way to get a reasonable figure is to take measurements.)

### Detailed Steps are Missing

The process for generating the above NFB figure isn't rocket science. I used a mundane approach, taking note of the input voltage source impedance, the output source impedance (which is just the collector resistance) that feeds back through the base resistor, and the usual voltage divider rules. Nothing from some secret stash of mystical equations. That's why it looks so simple, above.

The reason I'm not writing out the development, just yet, is that we still don't have any agreement about the source impedance issue and I've no way to go argue with your author about it, either. And I don't know what you are reading. Plus, I've limited time, right now. So I may walk you through this, but it will have to wait until I have the time and the inclination to write it out in fine detail. (I let an algebraic analyzer do much of the work to help me avoid transcription errors.)

### Summary

Please do take note that if \$R_{_\text{SRC}}=0\:\Omega\$ then \$B_{_\text{NFB}}=0\$! Just as I said would be the case. The base resistor can't have a negative feedback effect if the source impedance is zero. It's just not possible.

---

### Example Case

One of the nice things about this topology is how easy it is to bias it. Just use a base resistor that is about 50 to 100 times as large as the collector resistor.

Let's assume this isn't an educational design but instead a more serious design task. You will know what you want as the output impedance, because you will also know what you are driving with this stage and can work that detail out. You will also know your input source's impedance, too. And you will know the unloaded input signal's RMS voltage and your desired voltage gain at the output. (Not to mention the supply rail you have available, which has already been determined to be adequate.)

- \$R_{_\text{SRC}}\$ -- input source's impedance
- \$R_{_\text{OUT}}\$ -- this stage's desired output impedance
- \$V_{_{\text{IN}\left(RMS\right)}}\$ -- input source's unloaded maximum
- \$A_{v_\text{CL}}\$ -- the desired closed loop gain of the stage
- \$V_{_\text{CC}}\$ -- the single supply voltage (positive as we are thinking about NPN BJTs today.)

The maximum open loop gain you can expect (and the calculation will over-state, slightly, keep in mind) is:

$$A_{v_\text{OL}} = \frac{R_\text{C}}{r_e^{\,'}}\approx \frac{R_\text{C}}{\left[\frac{V_T}{I_{_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}}\right]}=\frac{R_\text{C}\:I_{_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}}{V_T}=\frac{R_\text{C}}{V_T}\cdot\frac{V_\text{CC}-V_{_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}}{R_\text{C}}=\frac{V_\text{CC}-V_{_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}}{V_T}$$

Take note that lower quiescent collector voltages mean higher open-loop voltage gains. (And yes, I fudged a bit to keep it simpler. It's actually \$\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}\$ smaller than that. But close enough for many purposes.)

If \$V_{_\text{CC}}=12\:\text{V}\$, then we can work out \$A_{v_\text{OL}} =\frac{12\:\text{V}-2.5\:\text{V}}{28\:\text{mV}}\approx 339\$. Round that up to \$A_{v_\text{OL}} =340\$.

Suppose we have decided that \$R_{_\text{OUT}}=2.7\:\text{k}\Omega\$. Then \$I_{_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}=\frac{12\:\text{V}-2.5\:\text{V}}{2.7\:\text{k}\Omega}\approx 3.5\:\text{mA}\$ and \$r_e^{\,'}\approx 8\:\Omega\$ (using \$28\:\text{mV}\$ again as the thermal voltage to be conservative.)

(Note: If you now compute \$\frac{2.7\:\text{k}\Omega}{8\:\Omega}=337.5\$, you will find this remarkably close to the above computed number. And if you took into account the \$\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}=\frac{200}{201}\$ fudge factor adjustment I didn't use above, it's almost exactly on target.)

At this point, we need to compute the base resistor. Given \$A_{_\text{CL}}=\frac{A_{_\text{OL}}}{1+A_{_\text{OL}}\cdot B_{_\text{NFB}}}\$ and what we know so far, you can find that \$B_{_\text{NFB}}=0.0170588\$. And let's assume that the input source impedance is \$R_{_\text{SRC}}=2\:\text{k}\Omega\$. (Audio line inputs are less than this.) Then we'd find that \$R_{_\text{B}}=145.957\:\text{k}\Omega\$. (Solve the equation, in reverse, to get that -- either by using algebra or else iterations if you prefer.) Round that to \$R_{_\text{B}}=150\:\text{k}\Omega\$.

So let's simulate that:

[image]

It's pretty easy to see that the achieved voltage gain, using a simulator, is \$A_{_\text{CL}}=48\$. As I said earlier, the calculations I provided will be just a tad bit too low for the NFB and therefore will predict a slightly higher voltage gain. But this is rather shockingly close, just the same.

Take note that the resulting quiescent collector voltage is something that "falls out" of this process. So you need to validate the design with one final set of calculations.

We expect the output signal to be:

$$V_{_{\text{OUT}\left(PEAK\right)}}=\sqrt{2}\cdot A_{v_\text{CL}}\cdot V_{_{\text{IN}\left(RMS\right)}}=707\:\text{mV}$$

Looking at the simulation, this seems about right, too. But you don't want the BJT saturated, either. And you can see that the minimum voltage at the collector is about \$2.4\:\text{V}\$. That's good, as it keeps the BJT in active mode and out of saturation.

So that's the final check.

Comment: @apadana Physics is all you need. Seriously. If you are well-experienced in physics, there's nothing that can stop you here. Nothing. It'll all be trivial. I *love* physics. It's my life. Lie groups and algebras, anti-de-sitter space, coxeter groups and polytropes, reflection spaces, finite and infinite group theory, etc. If you are into any of this stuff, you'll find this all a piece of cake.

Comment: @apadana Okay. There is that. I don't understand how it is that you can be quite experienced in physics and not see that issue. It must be a mental block, or something. Suppose you have a varying voltage source (a sine wave, for example.) This is a perfect source. Now, suppose you try and impose a foreign signal onto this voltage source through a resistance (your base resistance, for example.) Does the perfect source care? Does *anything* change what it does? The attempt to change the perfect voltage source *through* a resistor will ***fail***. It cannot affect it.

Comment: Just take a simple case: pop a voltage source into Spice. Make it a sine wave of some kind. Now add a resistor and tie one end of the resistor to this voltage source. Now, go get a ***different*** voltage source and stick it down. Connect this new voltage source (make it a sine or cosine or triangle wave, I don't care) and tie it back through the resistor to the first source. Make the magnitudes anything you like. I don't care. Now run it. Look at the output of the initial sine wave. Is it impacted? If you reduce/increase the resistance, does it matter? No, it does NOT. The output is the same.

Comment: @apadana I suspect that there is a mental block here. That's normal. It's not surprising. You need to "see" -- to visualize -- as others do. Sometimes, this means tearing down ideas you have that are getting in your way. And that can be a painful process. Just ask yourself... what is going on at the unknown left side of your schematic? What is it that is driving the circuit? If it is a perfect voltage source (zero impedance) then it perfectly drives the capacitor, too (assumed zero reactance.) This places the source right on the BJT base, right? I mean ***right there*** on it!! Yes?

Comment: @apadana I guess I need to listen to your mental voice and hear what it is telling you in order to help out. You need to write a lot about your own mental processes. I can listen to that. If I find something that's wrong, I can point out a better way to think about it. But I cannot do that if you don't expose your thinking to me. I mean, in detail. How do you see a voltage source? How does the DC blocking capacitor really work, as you see it? Precisely, I mean. Not just hand-waving? Why does that capacitor work, at all? Etc. I need to hear your mind work. Listen to the gears. I can help then.

Comment: @apadana Yes! It cannot be impacted. So there is no possible way that the base resistance, which is trying to pass along a negative feedback (180 degrees out of phase output at the collector) to the base can in any possible way affect a perfect driving source. It just cannot do that. The perfect driving source will just ignore it. So there's no possible NFB, as a result. The only way NFB can occur is if the driving source itself has limitations and has a source impedance to it. Then the other source (the collector output) can interfere. Otherwise? No.

Comment: @apadana One of the wonderful things, perhaps those most beautiful moments in life, happen when you can "see" as some of the better minds "see." The moment when things become clear, when simple ideas can suddenly explain the complex world around you. When you know ***why*** the cells at the edge of a leaf know why they are edge cells and not interior cells. (Very simple, once you know how it works.) When you can understand something complex using broadly applicable tools deduced into specifics. You get these from the better minds. You need to acquire them. They are important!!!

Comment: @apadana This is not just true in EE. (In fact, I consider EE a minor subset with lots of interesting nooks to it.) But it is most profoundly true in physics. You will go very, very, very far in physics if you can just acquire a few key ideas. Seriously. I've worked with some of the better physicists (my opinion, only) and I've watched how they "see." I've learned some of that from them. And it has made a huge difference in my life and the way I think about the world around us. Find your betters. Learn from them. Listen to their minds. Hear the songs they sing to you. Learn the melodies.

Comment: @apadana What does the mathematics of Einstein's special theory tell you? Look at the starting statements: \$x=c\cdot t\$ and \$x^{'}=c\cdot t^{'}\$ used to derive it. Think about these initial statements. What do they say to you? Do you "see" that these are two independent spaces, with only one factor tying them together, \$c\$? What are the implications of this? Could it be that **fermion** matter "lives" in isolated universes of their own, but that they exchange energy through a common means, **bosons**?

Comment: @apadana Could it be that bosons are the connective tissue between isolated fermionic matter and that the universe as we see it (3D+time) arrives through the tethering of isolated fermions via the bosonic energy exchange mechanism (entanglement) and the relationship of space and time presented by \$c\$? What does the universe look like from a bosonic perspective? Does time exist? Does space, itself? These are questions to consider. Ways to think about the world around us. Use your mind. Think. Listen. There are melodies there. You need to find them. Sorry to go on like this. But ideas matter.

Comment: @apadana I so much wish you the very best in life and the better people to know and learn from. It's just wonderful to listen and learn as well as interact and suggest. I spend one day a month with a string theorist from the University of Oregon, down in Eugene. We will sit outside, or in a car, or in his house and just talk. I was able to influence (create, actually) one of the chapters of his recent book on ADEX theory. It is a simple pleasure and my honor to have been some small part. I cannot express the joy of those moments. I wish you the best in your Ph.D!! Can you reference your paper?

Comment: In answer to your question that "what exactly do you mean when you ask for the NFB factor that the base resistance contributes?", I should say that in my question \$V_\text{i}\$ and \$V_\text{i}-\gamma V_\text{o}\$ are the base voltages for OL and CL, respectively, and \$V_\text{o}\$ is the collector voltage for CL. Here \$\gamma\$ is the feedback factor.

Comment: As far as I know, the relation \$A_{v_\text{OL}} = \frac{R_\text{C}}{r_e^{\,'}}\$ that you've written is true if the transistor is biased using, say, a two-resistor voltage divider, giving a dc voltage to the base. But if instead we simply remove the base resistor from the circuit shown in the question (isn't this what we mean by open loop here?), the transistor can be ON only for input cycles where the input signal is positive. For negative cycles, the transistor is OFF. Am I missing something?

Comment: @apadana It applies to any active mode BJT where the signal is applied to base and emitter and whose output is taken from collector and emitter or across RC. Doesn't matter how it's biased. What you are missing is ***why*** this is so. To figure that out, you need to study the Shockley diode equation and take its derivative to see how it behaves with respect to either a changing current or a changing applied voltage. The slope here is what is juxtapositioned against RC and determines the open loop voltage gain.

Comment: I used the word ON in the previous comment, which is usually used for BJT in saturation. But I meant active mode. Sorry for that.

Comment: @apadana Hmm. Well the answer then is that the BJT is never OFF, not even for negative cycles of the input signal. The reason is that the base resistor charges up the input capacitor so that it holds an average voltage across its plates. This is enough of a voltage difference that the input signal then "rides on top of it" and therefore gets an added DC bias to the source's AC signal (on the left side of the capacitor.) It will take a short moment while that charging happens. Before that time, the input signal shouldn't be applied, I suppose.

Comment: Assume that we have removed the base resistor (isn't this the open loop for the circuit in question?) and \$X_\text{C}=1/2\pi f C\$ is negligible. So the input capacitor has no effect. Based on Ebers-Moll equation, \$r_e^{\,'}=\frac{\mathrm{d}V_\text{BE}}{\mathrm{d}I_\text{C}}=V_\text{T}\frac{1/I_\text{S}}{I_\text{C}/I_\text{S}+1}\$ which equals \$V_\text{T}/I_\text{C}\$ if \$I_\text{C}/I_\text{S}\gg 1\$. I'm not sure if this holds when base-emitter junction is reverse biased.

Comment: @apadana We probably should handle these discussions either in a chat thing here or else via email. Do you have a preference? Email permits handling things, each on our own schedules, rather than trying to find coordinated time. But chat here has its own advantages, too. There are tradeoffs, that's all. It's your call.